# Can't see image in my tableView which are coming from JSON

Tags: ios, uiimageview, tableview

```
 NSDictionary *temp = [self.placeArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.textLabel.text = [temp objectForKey:@"name"];
UILabel *detailLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250,0,200,50)];
[detailLbl setText:[temp objectForKey:@"distance"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:detailLbl];
 cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[temp objectForKey:@"category"]];
```

On the last line i have set the image , but enable to see the image . please help me with this . And i can also not being able to unable segue .

Comment: can you check your code like this: cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];

Comment: Please check, whether your temp is having UIImage or URL or NSString having image name..

Comment: @user1980105 : Yeah can see image now , now please help me with URL

Comment: First JSON parsing , then transfered the data to an array then to temp  NSDictionary

Answer (score 3):

when you loading image from URL but no local,your tableView has drawrect,so when the image finish loading,you must reload tableView or reload the row .

you can use lazy load to get your image. start an request to get image in background,and callback use an block to set image.

this links can help you:
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Please share code , i am new to development and coding .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How do you have define your cell? In some cases using:

```
initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
```

instead:

```
initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
```

had fixing the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 NSString *imgUrl = @"";  //enter your url here  
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
cell.imageView.image = img;
```